# Не работает Integer.toString();

Tags: java, строки, int

Подскажите, не могу понять почему

```
int a = 231;
String str = Integer.toString(a);
```

возвращает

```
str = "[C@7f13d6e"
```

Comment: как именно ты проверяешь что тебе вернулось?

Comment: Проблема не в преобразовании числа в строку, а в том как и куда выводится переменная `str`

Comment: Код из вопроса работает правильно, в переменную `str` попадает строка `"231"`: https://ideone.com/DHMxTT Покажите как именно вы дальше используете переменную `str`.

Answer (score 1):

Сделай лучше:

```
int a = 231;
String str = String.valueOf(a);
```

Comment: @insolor Да, я чет ошибся. Писал на ночь глядя

Answer (score -1):

Такое часто бывает. При работе с массивами так же эта проблема будет встречаться.
Ты должен для начало str передать в toString(), а затем этот же toString перекинуть в String.valueOf:

```java
int a = 5;
String k = Integer.toString(a);
String k1 = String.valueOf(k);
System.out.println(k1);
```

Comment: `Такое часто бывает.` - так не бывает, просто автор вопроса делает что-то не так. Дополнительные шаги не нужны: достаточно или `Integer.toString(a)` или `String.valueOf(a)`.